# Faster to swap or assign a vector of strings?

Tags: c++, string, vector, swap

I have a class with a vector of strings and a function that assigns to that vector. I am changing my function to only assign to the vector if it's successful. To do that I use a temporary vector of strings in the function and then if the function is successful I assign to the vector of strings in the class.

For example:

```
class test
{
    vector<string> v;
    void Function()
    {
        vector<string> temp;
        v = temp; // Is this better?
        v.swap( temp ); // Or instead is this better?
    }
};
```

Comment: Seems like it would depend on whether swap is inline or not. `swap` certainly reads better. Also, premature optimization mayhaps?

Comment: @sircodesalot: More importantly, vector's `swap` only has to swap a few pointers, while assignment would have to create a whole new copy of the vector and all its strings.

Comment: Ah, didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++11, move it:

```
v = std::move(temp);
```

In ancient dialects, swapping would be better than copy-assigning (assuming the vector isn't empty as it is in your example).

Moving or swapping just needs to modify a few pointers, while copying requires memory allocation and other expensive shenanigans.

Comment: It appears I have `std::move` in Visual Studio 2010 so I'm going to give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

From the complexity point of view `std::swap` algorithm should be preferred.

```
vector<string> temp;
v = temp;           // complexity is linear in the size of the temp
v.swap( temp );     // complexity is constant
```